# MVC action method with jquery cookie value as parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies, parameter-passing, actionmethod

I was wondering is it possible that controllers action method take jquery cookie as param, something like this:


First i create a cookie with jquery like this:

```
$.cookie('SomeID', 1);
```

And then in controller i check for this value, something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? SomeID)
{
   if(SomeID != null)
   {
        // Do something...
   }
   else
   {
        // Do something else...
   }
}
```

This is not working for me to be honest...Tried using HttpCookie as type as well but still no luck...Any suggestions? 


Ah yes, forgot to mention if i do something like this in my controller action method, im able to get cookies value.

```
 var id = Request.Cookies["SomeID"].Value;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this:http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/03/07/aspnet-mvc-working-smart-with-cookies-custom-valueprovider/

Comment: @malkam tyvm m8, i managed to do it with your link.. thx again !